# Bootstrapping a datacenter using a snapshot

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

I am provisioning a new datacenter for an existing cluster. A rather shaky VPN connection is hindering me from making a `nodetool rebuild` bootstrap of the new DC. Interestingly, I have a full fresh database snapshot/backup at the same location as the new DC (transferred outside of the VPN). I am now considering the following approach:

1. Make sure my clients are using the old DC.
2. Provision the new nodes in new DC.
3. `ALTER` the keyspace to enable replicas on the new DC. This
   will start replicating all writes from old DC to new DC.
4. Before `gc_grace_seconds` after operation 3) above, use `sstableloader` to
   stream my backup to the new nodes.
5. For safety precaution, do a full repair.

Would this work?

Answer (score 1):

Our team also faced a similar situation. We run C* on Amazon EC2.

So first we prepared a snapshot of existing nodes and used them to create them for other datacenter(to avoid huge data transfer).

Procedure we followed:

1. Change replication strategy for all DC1 servers from simple-strategy to networkTopologyStrategy {DC1:x, DC2:y}

   1. change cassandra.yaml

      - endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
      - add a DC2 node IP to seeds list
      - others no need to change
   2. change cassandra-rackdc.properties

      - dc=DC1
      - rack=RAC1
   3. restart nodes one at a time.

      - restart seed node first
   4. Alter the keyspace.
      `ALTER KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'DC1' : x, 'DC2':y };`

      - Do it for all keyspace in DC1
   5. no need to repair.
   6. verify if the system is stable by query
2. Add DC2 servers as new data center to DC1 data center

   - https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html

     1. in DC2 db, cassandra.yaml > auto_bootstrap: false
     2. fix seeds, endpoint_snitch, cluster name

        - Node1 DC1 IP, Node2 DC2 IP as seeds.
        - recommended endpoint_snitch : GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
        - cluster name, same as DC1: test-cluster
     3. fix gossiping-property-file-snith : cassandra-rackdc.properties

        - dc=DC2
        - rack=RAC1
     4. bring DC2 nodes up one at a time

        - seed node first
     5. change keyspace to networkTopologyStrategy {DC1:x, DC2:y}
     6. since the DC2 db is copied from DC1, we should repair instead of rebuild

Comment: Great! Minor detail: Repair in 2.6 (which is very slow!) could have been avoided if you instead used `sstableloader` to load the snapshot into the new datacenter.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, the approach should work.** I've verified it with two knowledgeable people within the Cassandra community. Two pieces that are important to note, however:

- That the snapshot is being taken *efter* the mutations have started being written to the new datacenter.
- The backup must be fully imported before gc_grace_seconds after when the backup is taken. Otherwise you risk getting zombie data popping up.